# How to disable audio sink notifications from Firefox on Cinnamon?

Tags: firefox, cinnamon, desktop-environment, notifications, multimedia

Using Firefox 64 with Cinnamon (4.0.8) on Arch Linux.

Since upgrading to Firefox 62, I'm getting a system notification saying "input AudioIPC Server *x*%" whenever I start or stop playing media in Firefox.

Screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of Firefox window with 10 desktop notifications on the right]

This is a bit annoying, I'd like to stop getting these without disabling notifications altogether and my search attempts were unfruitful so far.

Apparently there's no way to disable notifications for a specific application. And I'm surprised I couldn't find other people complaining about this anywhere.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the [pasystray](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pasystray/) package. It was [reported on GitHub](https://github.com/christophgysin/pasystray/issues/103) and [fixed](https://github.com/joehillen/pasystray/commit/78ff5836775a6367d9e1788a9487d6137aec85da) on version 0.7.1.

I had also found a [report in the Manjaro forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/disable-volume-level-notifications-from-firefox/62091/2).